# Docker Proxy Setup

Tags: networking, docker, proxy

I want to build a proxy setup with docker.  I'd like to create a network `inside` which does not have access to the outside wold.  I was hoping to have one container (proxy) on one network `inside` and another container (app) on two networks: `inside` and `default`.  Thus app would have access to the outside world through the proxy container.  Is this setup possible?

The following is what I've been playing with but this does not work:

```
version: '2'

services:
  proxy:
    build: .
    container_name: proxy
    hostname: proxy
    networks:
      - inside
      - default

  app:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    networks:
      - inside
    command: python -m SimpleHTTPServer

networks:
  inside:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 10.0.1.0/24
        gateway: 10.0.1.251
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" how?

Comment: The `app` container can still ping out -- ping google.com works